# Linux can't format disk without error "mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system"

Tags: linux, disk

Ubuntu 20.04, format of disk gives error, how to solve?

```
# mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme6n2
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 3750232064 4k blocks and 468779008 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 9dc6c2f9-2297-4e44-a61d-481617e40158
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544, 1934917632, 
    2560000000

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system
```

from dmesg:

```
[31366539.313763] print_req_error: 9 callbacks suppressed
[31366539.313766] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 1842432 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.314934] buffer_io_error: 596 callbacks suppressed
[31366539.314938] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230304, lost async page write
[31366539.315492] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230305, lost async page write
[31366539.316038] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230306, lost async page write
[31366539.316566] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230307, lost async page write
[31366539.317080] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230308, lost async page write
[31366539.317582] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230309, lost async page write
[31366539.318073] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230310, lost async page write
[31366539.318554] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230311, lost async page write
[31366539.319021] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230312, lost async page write
[31366539.319482] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme6n2, logical block 230313, lost async page write
[31366539.319993] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 12854784 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.320929] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 163847936 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.321838] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 89918976 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.322782] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 63701504 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.323677] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 63704320 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.324621] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 163847680 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.329814] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 191112448 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.330868] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 191107584 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
[31366539.348081] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme6c10n2, sector 1719938048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4004800 phys_seg 32 prio class 0
```

but disk is good:

```
smartctl -a /dev/nvme6n2
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-91-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZWLR15THALA-00007
Serial Number:                      S6EXNE0R800894
Firmware Version:                   MPK90B5Q
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 15,360,950,534,144 [15.3 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      65
Number of Namespaces:               32
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          15,360,950,534,144 [15.3 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Mon Dec 19 18:06:52 2022 GMT
Firmware Updates (0x17):            3 Slots, Slot 1 R/O, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x00df):   Security Format Frmw_DL NS_Mngmt Self_Test MI_Snd/Rec Vrt_Mngmt
Optional NVM Commands (0x007f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Resv Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     71 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     84 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +    25.00W   22.00W       -    0  0  0  0      180     180

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 -     512       0         1
 1 -     512       8         3
 2 -    4096       0         0
 3 -    4096       8         2
 4 -    4096      64         3

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        32 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    388,363,814 [198 TB]
Data Units Written:                 1,230,470,407 [630 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 2,891,609,287
Host Write Commands:                6,972,724,748
Controller Busy Time:               2,098
Power Cycles:                       1
Power On Hours:                     7,181
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   0
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               32 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               32 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 3:               31 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 256 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

One thing I see that I do find strange - the device enumeration in dev/ for these drives is missing. So nvme6n2 is a partition (partition 2) on disk nvme6, however nvme6 is not listed as a device in dev/

```
# ls /dev/nvme[6,7,8]*
/dev/nvme6n2  /dev/nvme7n2  /dev/nvme8n2
```

example of a WORKING disk, you can see the device nvme5:

```
# ls /dev/nvme[5]*
/dev/nvme5  /dev/nvme5n1  /dev/nvme5n1p1  /dev/nvme5n1p2
```

Comment: My consumer grade Samsung NVMe drive uses a Samsung driver with 22.04. You may need 22.04 or newer Ubuntu to have latest kernel & drivers supported. Do you have latest firmware for that drive? For my Samsung they had a bootable ISO with just that one firmware as update. Are you not specifying partition? mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme6n2 like your nvme5n1p2

Comment: I doubt it's a firmware issue, as one of the other nvme U2 drives is a P1733 as well... probably i need to reboot the server, but that is really problematic, incase it doesn't come back up.

Comment: Can you confirm drive is gpt partitioned so it sees partition to format?

Comment: how can i see that?

Comment: You can see it in `parted -l`. For instance: `sudo parted -l /dev/nvme6n2 | grep 'Partition Table'`.

Comment: ```Error: /dev/nvme6n2: unrecognised disk label
Model: SAMSUNG MZWLR15THALA-00007 (nvme)                                  
Disk /dev/nvme6n2: 15.4TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

Model: SAMSUNG MZPLJ3T2HBJR-00007 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 3201GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  107GB   107GB   linux-swap(v1)        swap
 2      107GB   3201GB  3093GB  ext4```

Comment: ```# sudo parted -l /dev/nvme6n2 | grep 'Partition Table'
Error: /dev/nvme8n2: unrecognised disk label
Error: /dev/nvme7n2: unrecognised disk label
Error: /dev/nvme6n2: unrecognised disk label```

Comment: i'm sry it looks so shit, but i didn't make this website.

Comment: Formatting supported in question where it should be posted to make it easy to read. But drive has no label, nor partitions. `sudo parted /dev/nvme6n2  mklabel gpt` Make absolutely sure that is correct drive as it will erase drive.  see `man parted` then create partitions & format those partitions.